# How many times a number appears in a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, count

I need to find a way to count how many times each number from 0 to 9 appears in a random matrix created using `np.random.randint()`

```
import numpy as np
p = int(input("Length of matrix: "))
m = np.random.randint(0,9,(p,p))
print(m)
```

For example if length of matrix = 4

- [[3 4 6 5]  [3 4 4 3]  [4 2 4 8]  [6 8 2 7]]

How many times does the number 4 appear? It should return 5.

Comment: First, figure out how you would do it by hand.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to get this pretty simply:

```
list(m.flatten()).count(x)
```

Another option which is probably faster, is to use the numpy builtin [`count_nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```
np.count_nonzero(m == x)
```

Hooray builtin functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sum` function:

```
In [52]: m = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,4))
In [53]: m
Out[53]: 
array([[8, 8, 2, 1],
       [2, 7, 1, 2],
       [8, 6, 8, 7],
       [5, 2, 5, 2]])

In [56]: np.sum(m == 8)
Out[56]: 4
```

`m == 8` will return a boolean array contains True for each 8 then since python evaluates the True as 1 you can sum up the array items in order to get the number of intended items.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the frequency from all matrix elements, here's a simple solution using [numpy.ndarray.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import numpy as np
import collections

p = int(input("Length of matrix: "))
m = np.random.randint(0, 9, (p, p))
print(m)
print(collections.Counter(m.flatten()))
```

For example, when p=3 you'd get something like this:

```
[[8 4 8]
 [5 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
Counter({1: 5, 8: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the matrix and then use the list `count()` method:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
p = int(input("Length of matrix: "))
m = np.random.randint(0,9,(p,p))
print(m)
flat = [item for sublist in m for item in sublist]
flat.count(4)
```

Comment: [Counting a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python) is even easier than that: `flat.count(x)` is sufficient.

Comment: Also, numpy has a [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

`list(m.flatten()).count(x)`

Comment: I'm curious which method is faster, since you still have to convert this to a list @TemporalWolf

Comment: Usually built-in functions are faster than custom ones. You're welcome to `timeit`

Comment: @TemporalWolf This is incorrect, NumPy functions will be much faster than built in Python functions if the array is of a relevant size.

Comment: @Daniel I was including the numpy built-ins (like `flatten`), comparing them to rofls' custom list comprehension solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try numpy unique function with argument return_counts=True (see: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

```
import numpy as np
p = int(input("Length of matrix: "))
m = np.random.randint(0,9,(p,p))
# print(m)
un, nm = np.unique(m, return_counts = True)
# if number that you are looking for is 1 then:
print(nm[un==1])
```

Comment: Changed it. Hope it works now. Thanks for pointing it out